# numpy select columns and rows with lists

Tags: python, numpy

I do have an array and would like to pick specific rows and specific columns. E.g:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.random.rand(10,5)
```

What works:

```
rows = [1,2,3]
col = [1,2]
X[rows,:]
X[:,col]
```

However, I cannot select:

```
X[row,col]
```

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: I think you want `X[np.ix_(rows, col)]`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30917753/subsetting-a-2d-numpy-array/30917921#30917921

Comment: No worries - if that answers your question, should we mark this as a duplicate?

Comment: Yes, it is a duplicate